# how can I count number of rows that contains text/numbers in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count all rows in a range that contains either text or numbers, what formula can I use for that? I tried this but it does not count correct...

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B50;"*") + SUMPRODUCT( -- ISTEXT(B2:B50))
```

data/text in cells can be like this...

```
    S
    160
    XS
    M
```

Comment: Maybe `COUNTA`?

Comment: Sweet, I didnt know about that one. Worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To count both text and numbers, use `COUNTA` > `=COUNTA(B2:B50)`

Be aware that this does also count empty formulas!

Comment: @MTplus, Don't forget to accept the answer to return the favor.

Answer (score 1):

To make your original formulas work.

You can use

`=COUNTIF(B2:B50,"<>")`

or

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B50<>""))`

However, @JvdV formula is more appropriate. If you need to ignore formula blanks then the `SUMPRODUCT` formula can be used.